# Variable contains in the array? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, contain

how to check that the variable occurs in an array?

In Example

```
var X = 5;
var newArray = [1,2,5]
```

And now something like this

```
if(X.isin(newArray)
{ document.write( "YES");}
```

something like this exist? :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (newArray.indexOf(X) > -1) {
    // value X exists in newArray
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: But are you sure this works in all browsers? In the "compatibility" section it says it might not be available in all browsers.

Comment: @mohkhan: 1. there are a list of supported browsers on the link 2. There is a shim function definition for the browsers don't have its support natively

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [JQuery](http://jquery.com)'s `inArray()` method - it solves compatibility problems. Code:

```
var X = 5;
var newArray = [1,2,5]
if ($.inArray(X, newArray) > -1) {
    alert('is in array');
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zKs8L/1/).